# Does the method get() and paginate() work in laravel 7.3

Tags: php, laravel, get, laravel-7, php-7.3

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Exam;
    use App\Module;
    use App\Dapartment;
    use DB;


    class PastexController extends Controller
    {
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $xams=DB::table('exams')
            ->join('modules', 'modules.id', '=', 'exams.module_code_id')
            ->where('exams.views', '!=', '0')
            ->select('exams.views','modules.name_of_modue', 'modules.code','exams.id','exams.yr', 'exams.month')
            
            ->get()->sortByDesc('views')
       

    ->paginate(7);
        return view('pastex/home', ['xams'=>$xams]);
    }
    }
```

This is the error message I m getting
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: I want to paginate the results bt its  giving me an error

Comment: What exactly is the problem?! Yes `->get()` and `->paginate()` do work in Laravel 7.3

Comment: "_bt its giving me an error_" Please [edit] your question and paste the error message you get

Comment: I don't see any pagination code here.

Comment: yes it works in laravel 7.3 @PhilmonChigwagwa

Answer (score 2):

Using [`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-results) returns a collection, while [`paginate`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination) belongs to the Query Builder. You'll need to use `paginate` instead of `get`, and move the ordering to the query builder instead of the collection.

```
 $xams=DB::table('exams')
            ->join('modules', 'modules.id', '=', 'exams.module_code_id')
            ->where('exams.views', '!=', '0')
            ->select('exams.views','modules.name_of_modue', 'modules.code','exams.id','exams.yr', 'exams.month')
            ->orderByDesc('exams.views')
            ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: After following the above suggestion it worked  ok but it was not placing the most viewed paper on top  of the list

Comment: Make sure you added the `orderByDesc` line, that tells the database how to sort the query.